# Swift: BLE not update characteristics

Tags: swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I send a 0x11 byte to the TX but nothing happens, the function

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?)
```

Is never called. Here is my code ..

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    peripheral.delegate = self
    //peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    peripheral.discoverServices([CBUUID(string: "6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E")])
    print("Connected successfully to the device")

    //On stop le scan
    centralManager?.stopScan()
}
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    print("\n\n\n ✅ READING SERVICES OF PERIPHERAL ❤️ \(peripheral.name!) ❤️")

    for service in peripheral.services! {
        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        print(service)
    }
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    print("\n\n  READING CHARARCTERISTICS OF  \(service.uuid) ")

    let NORDIC_UART_TX_CHARACTERISTIC = CBUUID(string: "6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e")
    let NORDIC_UART_RX_CHARACTERISTIC = CBUUID(string: "6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e")

    for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
            // Tx:
            if characteristic.uuid == NORDIC_UART_TX_CHARACTERISTIC {
                print("Tx char found: \(characteristic.uuid)")
                let command:[UInt8] = [0x11]
                let sendData: Data = Data(command)

                peripheral.writeValue(sendData, for: characteristic, type:.withResponse)
            }

            // Rx:
            if characteristic.uuid == NORDIC_UART_RX_CHARACTERISTIC {
                    print("Rx char found: \(characteristic.uuid)")
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
            }
    }
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?){
    print("characteristic changed: \(characteristic)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't linked any documentation, but I'm assuming from the names that this is a serial protocol; you write on the Tx characteristic and read on the Rx. I'm also assuming that the documentation says you should get back a response after writing 0x11. What do you expect to receive? (This is a strange UART message. Generally they're in ASCII and often \n terminated. Where are the docs for this?)

That said, the problem is likely that you're writing on the Tx characteristic before you begin observing the Rx characteristic. That means the flow is like this:

- Send 0x11 to Tx. Device accepts 0x11.
- Subscribe to Rx. Device accepts that, and will notify you of the next change on Rx.
- Nothing else happens.

You need to make sure you discover all your characteristics and subscribe to Rx before you send on Tx.

Comment: I have to write to TX 0x11 to receive the battery level, what does it mean to subscribe to the protocol rx and how to do it?

Comment: You are doing it: `peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)`. You need to make sure you've done that before you call the `write`.